# How can I determine in which period am I hover in edit mode in ganttResource anychart 8.2.0

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

I'm creating a POC for a Gantt project for my company. I'm using the Resource Gantt from Anychart version 8.2.0. I'm trying to determine in which period am I, in order to set a custom tooltip. If I'm not in edit mode my code works, but if in edit mode, it doesn't! I can't determine in which period we are, because the periodIndex is undefined. Can anyone help me?

My custom tooltip code:

```
  //custom timeLine Tooltip
  timeLine.tooltip().useHtml(true);
  timeLine.tooltip().format(function (e) {
    var tooltip = '';
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var item = e.item;
    var parentElement = item.getParent();
    if (parentElement !== null ) { 
      tooltip = 'Project: ' + parentElement.get('name') + '<br>';
    } else {
      tooltip = '';
    }
    if (e.periodIndex !== undefined){
        startDate = e.period.start;
            endDate = e.period.end;
        tooltip = tooltip + 'Period Id: ' + e.period.id + '<br>';
        tooltip = tooltip + 'Start Date: ' + startDate + '<br>' + 'End Date: ' + endDate;
    } else {
      var periodsArr = item.get('periods');
        startDate = periodsArr[0].start;
      endDate = periodsArr[periodsArr.length-1].end;
      tooltip = tooltip + 'From ' + startDate + ' to ' + endDate;
    }
    return tooltip;
  });
```

I have a sample in here: https://jsfiddle.net/migrafik/yobu0t6y/6/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when the LiveEdit mode is enabled, you hover the period along with editing thumbs and other elements which implement this feature. That's why the period info is not available. So, with the current version of library 8.2.1 this cannot be done. I will suggest this improvement to our dev team and probably in future releases, the period info will become available. I will notify you about the ETA and when the improvement gets released.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but in version 8.0.1 that was possible!

Comment: Yes, the internal implementation has changed in 8.2 version of AnyGantt and it leads us to this issue. As I said I will report it to our dev team and will fix this behavior. Thank you for this report!

Comment: Our dev team will fix this issue in summer 2018 updates. We will notify you when the update becomes available. Thank you for your report!